# Filter Out Search results based on custom business logic

Tags: solr

I am building a search solution and I have to filter the returned results based on some custom logic.

At this point is important to understand what logic will need to be in place.

Let's consider the following documents (Cars) with the following fields:

```
<id></id>
<Model></Model>
<Make></Make>
<Offering></Offering>
<year></year>
```

My search targets to return to client the different versions of a specific model. I want to the client ideally to send me the id of the car it wants to perform the search. (additional fields can be send as well)

In order to match a car, i want to match Model and Make and Year (only for cars offered toBuy).
If the year is offered as rent I dont want Year to be considered(only Make and Model for rented cars)!

Any ideas how to approach the problem?

Kind regards,
Manos

Comment: You can try to use LocalParams: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/LocalParams But I would advise you to do it in your code: depending on some parameters, build different Solr queries.

Comment: Do you mean some code that will be between SOLR and Client?

Comment: Yes, like controller, js in UI, etc. Depends on your application